# Regex to match dates

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a HTML input that have three patterns like this:

**Pattern one**

```
</div>

<div class="myclass">
```

**Pattern two**

```
</div>

    <p class="ProductMeta">29-06-2011</p>

<div class="myclass">
```

**Pattern trhee**

```
</div>

    <p class="ProductMeta">29/06/2011</p>

<div class="myclass">
```

I'm trying to create a RegEx that can catch the tree dates: empty, with dashes and with slashes. I think i need some kind of nested groups, but can't make it work.

This is the RegEx I've created:

```
Regex r = new Regex(
                @"src=""</div>\s+<p class=""ProductMeta"">([\d\/\-]+)"
                , RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

And tried the following to make the group optional:

```
Regex r = new Regex(
                    @"src=""</div>[\s+<p class=""ProductMeta"">([\d\/\-]+)]?"
                    , RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Can anyone help me?

The console test does the following to print on screen:

```
foreach (Match m in mcl)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value.Replace("-","/") + " - " + m.Groups[5].Value);
            }

            Console.Read();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make the `[]`'s an optional group.  Only `()` can be optional.

```
var test1 = 
@"</div>
<div class=""myclass"">";

var test2 =
@"</div>
    <p class=""ProductMeta"">29-06-2011</p>
<div class=""myclass"">";

var test3 = 
@"</div>
    <p class=""ProductMeta"">29/06/2011</p>
<div class=""myclass"">";

string re = @"</div>\s+(<p class=""ProductMeta"">(\d\d([-/])\d\d\3\d\d\d\d))?";
Regex regExpr = new Regex(re, RegexOptions.Multiline);

Console.WriteLine(regExpr.Match(test1).Groups[2].Value); //== ""
Console.WriteLine(regExpr.Match(test2).Groups[2].Value); //== "29-06-2011" 
Console.WriteLine(regExpr.Match(test3).Groups[2].Value); //== "29/06/2011"
```

Answer (score 1):

You only have 1 group in the regular expression you created (that first one), but you are taking the 6th.

```
  Regex r = new Regex(
            @"src=""</div>\s+<p class=""ProductMeta"">([\d\/\-]+)"
            , RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
  foreach (Match m in mcl)
     Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value.Replace("-","/"));
```

The second regex is completely wrong because you put the stuff you're trying to match in a character class (which means it will match any single character from your list.)  So, `[\s+p ]` would match a whitespace character, a space , or a plus `+`, or a `p`.

Comment: I had other groups, forgot to change the number to post here. I'm fixing it now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Id split this into two regexe's

First match the p class:

```
<p\s(?:[^\s>]*?\s)*?(class="ProductMeta")>.*
```

Then match the date (US & UK):

```
/^((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])|(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))[- /.](19|20)?\d\d$/gm
```

Im not saying its perfect, but it works :)

Comment: That's a lot of extra regex to match only to go part way.  "31/02-2011" would match.  Probably better to capture any digit looking thing after ProductMeta and then use something like DateTime.TryParse do verify the digits form a reasonable date.  But still, A for effort :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Regex: `</div>\s*<p class="ProductMeta">(\d{2}[-/]\d{2}[-/]\d{4})`